# Automorphism and cyclicity

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group. Show that if ${\rm Aut}(G)$ (the group of automorphism of $G$ ) is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian, and if $G$ is additionally finite, show that $G$ is cyclic.

**I need the second part of the question.**

For the first part, I use this lemma

> **Lemma** Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Now for a group $G$, if ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Solution:

Let suppose $G$ is a group with $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ cyclic. Then, considering the conjugation morphism $\gamma: G \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ sending $g$ to the inner automorphism $x \mapsto g x g^{-1}$, we have that $\operatorname{ker}(\gamma)=Z(G)$, so that $G / Z(G) \cong \operatorname{Im}(\gamma) \leq \operatorname{Aut}(G)$, and by previous point $G_{1}:=G / Z(G)$ is cyclic. Take a generator $t . Z(G)$ for $G_{1}$, by fixing a suitable $t \in G$. Then every element $x \in G$ can be written as $x=t^{n} c$, with $c \in Z(G)$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We now prove that $t \in Z(G)$, so that $Z(G)=G$ and $G$ is abelian. Let $x \in G$ and take the commutator $[x, t]=x t x^{-1} t^{-1}$. Writing down $x=t^{n} c$, we get
$$
[x, t]=t^{n} c t c^{-1} t^{-n} t^{-1}=t^{n+1} c c^{-1} t^{-n-1}=1_{G}
$$
because $c \in Z(G)$. Hence $t \in Z(G)=G$ and we are done.

Let's use  this lemma.

> **Lemma.** Every cyclic group is abelian.

Since ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic, we have that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is abelian.

By first part, we have that $G$ is abelian.

Since  $G$ is finite abelian and ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is abelian, I need to deduce that $G$ is cyclic but I am missing the argument.

I am thinking  of If $G$ is finite and not cyclic, it has a factor $C_{p^r}$ $C_{p^s}$.

Could someone help me finish the argument?

Comment: Show that for $1\leq r\leq s$, the automorphism group of $C_{p^r}\times C_{p^s}$ is not cyclic (Hint: the automorphism group contains two distinct subgroups of order $p-1$). Conclude that if $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is cyclic and $G$ is finite, then the $p$-parts of $G$ must be cyclic. Deduce that $G$ is cyclic.